# Does Opencv allow you to compute the 3x4 perspective transformation using 6 points?

Tags: python, opencv, computational-geometry

I want to compute a 3x4 matrix transformation, in homogeneous coordinates, that transforms 3d world points to 2d image points. My problem is that in the documentation and tutorials of the function getPerspectiveTransformation the default matrices are either 3x3 for perspective or 2x3 in affine transformations.

Is there any built in function to compute the 3x4 matrix?

I have read the tutorials, some books on computer vision and I know the matrix that transforms 3d to 2d is 3x4. It is necessary to input 6 points to get this matrix and in the examples I find for opencv they are using 4, so I guess this is a 2d to 2d transformation not what I need.

cv2.getPerspectiveTransform
cv2.getAffineTransform

I used these functions but it didn't work, I used cv2.circle function to plot what was supposed to be a straigh line on the image and I got curved lines. Obviously I was not using the proper matrix transformation.

Comment: "that transforms 3d world points to 2d image points " is typical Image Projection method. Are you asking how to get 3X4 projection matrix K[R|t] or are you asking for something else?   where K is constructed with only focal and principal points. R and t are assumed to be diagonal and zero vector for non-moving camera origin.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about that matrix. But I am not interested in dissecting the matrix into another ones with physical parameters etc. I just need the matrix itself, I don't need neither intrinsic camera parameters nor external camera parameters.

Comment: if you look at https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html. To get 3D point projected down to 2D is it actually done by using intrinsic camera fx fy cx cy.  So I`m confused on what you are asking. You dont want camera intrinsic and you wnant to project?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know fx, fy, cx, cy or anything else. I just know what is the position of a few points in the real world, and I know what pixel they are in. With that information I was able to compute the vanishing points but I don't know how to get the matrix because of the homogeneous constants.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard OpenCV function to do this. Its unconventional. So you have to list down the equation with matrix K full of 9 unknown variables. Write them down in plain form and with 9 points you should be able to solve it. Follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-j704F6F7Q to list down equations. It is finding the fundamental matrix which is exactly the case where your intrinsics are unknown.

Comment: Ok I understand. Well it is a 3x4 so it contains 12 parameters, 11 if you fix one of the elements. Thanks for your help and the links.

Comment: it not a full rank matrix. Therefore you don't need a full 12. There are similar sample  E.g for essential matrix it has 9 parameters but because it is only rank 2, you only need 5 points.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wish, you could try to create your own code that does that. Here is my "theoretical" take on this problem, if it is of any help to you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks man. Every recommendation is welcome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -5):

Yes of course there is. Just look for the computeThreeByFourMatrix() function in the OpenCV library documentation. It is all there

Comment: This answer can be improved by linking to the relevant documentation and extracting the relevant parts that answer the OP's question in your answer

Comment: Are you kidding me?

Comment: There's no such function [in the code base](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=computeThreeByFourMatrix) (same for contrib), let alone in the documentation.

Comment: I think Martin didn't write a serious answer.

Comment: I use OpenCV for 10 years, Never head of such function. And OpenCV naming conversion usually denotes math concept like projection and Rodigious which can directly associate to its methods.